# I am trying to explain my gf how functions work.. heres the code in python but i cant get a way out

Tags: python-2.7

```
askForAge()
takeDecision()

def askForAge():
    age = int(input("Enter Age: "))

def takeDecision():
    if age>=12:
        allowPermission
        return
    else:
        considerPermission()
        return

def allowPermission():
    print("You are allowed in the park. Enjoy!")

def considerPermission():
    if age<9:
        print("You are not allowed in the park.")

    elif age>=9 and age<12:
        print("You need supervision.")
```

How does this not work? I am trying to explain functions to my gf. I calling the functions and defined them aswell.

Answer (score 0):

You are using age as a local variable, it doesn't keep it's value once each function returns.

You need to mark `age` global so that multiple functions can work on it. Do this by declaring it outside of the functions with a dummy value, and prefix each function's body with `global age`.

In addition, you need to add parentheses to your call of `allowPermission`.